# Cannot drag and drop upload file with custom Master

Tags: custom-masterpage, user-experience

We have migrated our SharePoint 2010 farm to new SharePoint 2013 environment. Since we have a custom Master pages/Layout at the old environment, we used the old CSS/images to generate new Master pages/images/css to be used on new farm.

So far everything is working as old environment. But I just found if I change the site back to Oslo Master pages, users can drag and drop upload file to document library. However the "drag and drop area" is not existing with our custom Master.

What should I check to repair this feature? Any reference material is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In the library the drag and drop was working , but not in publishing page with the library app part. 
Hence I added the below code within a script editor in the page . This script can also be added to the master page or page layout.

```
<script type="text\javascript">
Function DragDropFix() {
        var L1 = "";
        var L2 = "";
        var head = $('head');
        if ($("[src*='/_layouts/15/sp.core.js']").length == 0)
            head.append(L1);
        if ($("[src*='/_layouts/15/cui.js']").length == 0)
            head.append(L2);
}
</script>
```

[Reference Link](https://www.plusconsulting.com/Blogs/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=55)

Answer (score 0):

Ducument libraries does support Drag'n'Drop functionality, but a Pages Library doesn't. And since a Masterpage Gallery, you can't drag'n'drop master pages to that library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so by just migrating Custom MasterPage and Css to SP2013 will resolve all your issue related to designing part.

As due to heaving change in UI perspective in SP2013, SP2010 CSS and masterpage will not allow you to use SP2013 browser based functionality like drag n drop.

You should need to recreate your masterpage and UI file in SP2013 itself using design manager according to your need.

Comment: I am going to recreate my masterpage. But I don't know what to do first. In fact I created current masterpage with SP2013 design manager. I must miss something but I am not sure.